# Getting string from database

Tags: java, android, sql, database

I have database like here in [section 4.3](http://www.vogella.com/articles/AndroidSQLite/article.html#databasetutorial_database).

How do i get an item from this database and convert it to a `String` when I want to display it in `TextSwitcher` in a separate `Activity`?

I know how to add data to this db and show it in an `ArrayList` as in the example but I can't use any items from this `ArrayList`. Please help me deal with this problem.

I try to do as you said but always I replace something wrong and Eclipse shows that method query is not applicable for the arguments, please can anyone can help me and say me what should be

```
uri, projection, selection, selectionArgs, sortOrder
```

I have the same names as in the tutorial which is linked in my question, and I want to get string which number is value of my mCounter variable.

Answer (score 0):

In your `SecondActivity` query for the value you want from the database.

You can use a [`ContentResolver`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/ContentResolver.html).

```
ContentResolver contentResolver = this.getContentResolver();

Cursor cursor = 
    contentResolver.query(
        uri, projection, selection, selectionArgs, sortOrder);

String myStringValue = 
    cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(columnName));
```

- Replace `uri` with the uri of your table.
- Replace `projection` with the columns you want from this query. This needs to be an array of `Strings`
- Replace `selection` with the `where` clause for this query.
- Replace `selectionArgs` with the values for the arguments in your
  `selection`. This needs to be an array of `Strings`.
- Replace `sortOrder` with the sorting order, this can be `null` if you
  do not care what order the results are in.

The last line of code will get the `String` from the database as a `String`.

- Replace `columnName` with the column name where your target String
  resides.